# Summing data from two arrays, grouped and sorted by date

Tags: ruby, array

I have multiple multidimensional arrays that each have the same structure with different lengths.

```
arr1 = [["23 Jan",3],["29 Jan",10],["19 Jan",23],["25 Jan",23]]
arr2 = [["31 Jan",7],["29 Jan",12],["01 Feb",4]]
```

My result would be a merged array without duplicate dates ordered by the date. For the dates that get combined, like `29 Jan` above, I would add the second values together.

Here is what the outcome to the above arrays should be:

```
arr = [["19 Jan",23],["23 Jan",3],["25 Jan",23],["29 Jan",22],["31 Jan",7],["01 Feb",4]]
```

As you can see the two with the date, `29 Jan`, were combined and added.

Here is my current solution:

```
(arr1 | arr2).group_by(&:first).
  map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last).inject(:+)] }.
  sort_by { |x| x.first.to_date }
```

Which does indeed get my the correct result, I just want to refactor it. Any suggestions/insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks great already, if you ask me. Other than perhaps being more descriptive than `k`, `v`, and `x`, I don't see any need to refactor anything here. I'd probably write the same thing.

Comment: I don't understand the use of `|`, two pairs are not duplicated if they are on different arrays, aren't they? It seems you need `uniq` for *each* array.

Comment: @tokland I *think* it's used instead of `Array#+`. Here it will have the unfortunate (or desired?) effect of ignoring items in `arr2` that are equal to items in `arr1` (e.g. if `["1 Jan", 1]` is in both `arr1` and `arr2`, the OPs code will return `["Jan 1", 1]` instead of `["Jan 1", 2]`). If this is intentional, both answers here are not valid, unfortunately. Could you clarify Justin?

Comment: @tokland, you actually just found a flaw in my solution that I overlook. britishtea, it appears at first glance your solution addresses this.

Comment: Could `arr1` contain `["23 Jan",3]` and `["23 Jan",5]`. If "yes" (I'm guessing the answer is "no") and if `arr2` contained `["23 Jan",7]`, would `["23 Jan",3+5+7]` be part of your result?  The efficiency as well as the correctness of the solution depends on whether `arr1` or `arr2` can contain pairs with the same date.

Comment: Good question @CarySwoveland. No array would have the same date. Each array comes from a `group` query on a different table that returns a multidimensional array. Each array's first value is the date, and the second value is the count. No two dates would be the same for one array. I'm taking these multiple arrays (3 at the moment) and combining them so I have one array with unique dates with their counts added together, which I'm then graphing on a Line Chart and presenting these over the 30 day period. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I added your method to the benchmark after making a correction and removing `to_date`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as if you have chosen the wrong data structure. The multidimensional `Array` looks very much like a `Hash`. Even your code mentions the terms key (`k`) and value (`v`).

If you were to use a `Hash`, you could use [`Hash#merge`](http://devdocs.io/ruby/hash#method-i-merge):

```ruby
one = Hash[[["23 Jan",3],["29 Jan",10],["19 Jan",23],["25 Jan",23]]]
two = Hash[[["31 Jan",7],["29 Jan",12],["01 Feb",4]]]

one.merge(two) { |_value, old, new| old + new }
# => {"23 Jan"=>3, "29 Jan"=>22, "19 Jan"=>23, "25 Jan"=>23, "31 Jan"=>7, "01 Feb"=>4}
```

<sup>**Note**: If you're using a recent version of Ruby, you can replace `Hash::[]` with `Array#to_hash`</sup>

If you really do need multidimensional `Array`s, you could still use `Hash`es internally and convert to the required format (`Hash#to_a`) when needed.

Comment: Yea I need the result to be a multidimensional array, but of course converting the hash to an array does that very well. this is also much more descriptive than my original solution. The only thing left is to sort the hashes by date.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is algorithmically fine.  My main critique is that it isn't obvious at a glance what the code does.  In particular, `k`, `v`, `:first`, and `:last` can only be understood if you mentally step through the code to follow what the data structure looks like at each point.

I'd like to present an alternative solution.  It's much less clever — four statements instead of one expression.  However, it's easier to see that there is a date-to-value mapping, that I'm grouping by date, summing the values, and sorting by date.

```
aggregator = Hash.new(0)
arr1.each { |date, val| aggregator[date.to_date] += val }
arr2.each { |date, val| aggregator[date.to_date] += val }
aggregator.to_a.sort_by { |date, val| date }
```

In addition, I've chosen to call `#to_date` earlier.  Presumably, your `#to_date` method would treat `"01 Feb"` and `"1 Feb"` equally, in case your input is sloppy.

Comment: Yea, I couldn't agree more that my code presented could have be written in a clearer way. This definitely does a good job of that. The returned array's dates are formatted incorrectly though, `[Mon, 19 Jan 2015, 23]`, but this can be fixed easily.

Comment: I added your method to the benchmark after removing `to_date`.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the arrays were large and you were looking for an efficient solution.

Let `arr1` and `arr2` denote the two arrays, with `arr2` being the smaller of the two.

First, convert `arr2` to a hash:

```
h2 = Hash[arr2]
```

Now map each element of `arr1` and append to the result the elements of `arr2` that do not have matching dates among the elements of `arr1`:

```
arr1.map { |k1,v1| [k1, h2.key?(k1) ? v1 + h2.delete(k1) : v] }.concat(h2.to_a)
```

Note that `h2.delete(k)` does double-duty: it deletes the key-value pair `k,v2` from `h2` and returns `v2` to be added to `v1`.

You can of course tack on `.sort` to sort the array by date.

I suspect this may be reasonably fast considering that only one hash is constructed and that is for the smaller of the two arrays.

Let's see how this compares with the other methods that have been suggested.

**Test case**

```
def test(n1, n2, f1)
  m = [(n1*f1).to_i, n2].min # elements of `arr1` in `arr2`
  [Array.new(n1) { |i| [i,i] }.shuffle, 
   Array.new(n2) { |i| [i+m-n2,i+i] }.shuffle]
end
```

Suppose, for example, `arr1` and `arr2` are to have `10` and `8` tuples, respectively, and  in `10*0.5 => 5` cases, the first element of a tuple in `arr1` matches the first element of a tuple in `arr2`. Thus `0-5 => 5` tuples in `arr1` have no match in `arr2` and `8-5 => 3` tuples in `arr2` have no match in `arr1`.

Then

```
arr1, arr2 = test(10,8,0.5)
  #=> [[[7, 7], [0, 0], [2, 2], [4, 4], [3, 3], [5, 5], [1, 1], [8, 8], [9, 9], [6, 6]],
  #   [[-2, 2], [-3, 0], [3, 12], [-1, 4], [4, 14], [0, 6], [2, 10], [1, 8]]]
arr1.sort
  #=> [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9]] 
arr2.sort
  #=> [[-3, 0], [-2, 2], [-1, 4], [0, 6], [1, 8], [2, 10], [3, 12], [4, 14]]
```

**Methods to be benchmarked**

```
def justin(arr1, arr2)
  (arr1 + arr2).group_by(&:first)
               .map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last).inject(:+)] }
               .sort_by { |x| x.first }
end
```

I've corrected `justin` by changing `arr1 | arr2` to `arr1 + arr2`, and removed `to_date`.

```
def btea(arr1, arr2)
  one = Hash[arr1]
  two = Hash[arr2]
  one.merge(two) { |_value, old, new| old + new }.to_a
end
```

In `btea` I converted the merged hash back to an array.

```
def success(arr1, arr2)
  aggregator = Hash.new(0)
  arr1.each { |date, val| aggregator[date] += val }
  arr2.each { |date, val| aggregator[date] += val }
  aggregator.to_a.sort_by { |date, val| date }
end
```

I removed `.to_date` in `success`.

```
def cary(arr1, arr2)
  h2 = Hash[arr2]
  arr1.map { |d1,n1| [d1, h2.key?(d1) ? n1 + h2.delete(d1) : n1] }.concat(h2.to_a)
end
```

**Confirm methods give the same results**

```
arr1, arr2 = test(1000,800,0.8)

bt = btea(arr1, arr2).sort
su = success(arr1, arr2).sort

justin(arr1, arr2).sort == bt #=> true
bt == su                      #=> true
su == cary(arr1, arr2).sort   #=> true
```

**Benchmark code**

```
require 'benchmark'

def bench(arr1, arr2)
  Benchmark.bm(10) do |bm|
    bm.report "justin" do
      justin(arr1, arr2)
    end
    bm.report "btea" do
      btea(arr1, arr2)
    end
    bm.report "success" do
      success(arr1, arr2)
    end
    bm.report "cary" do
      cary(arr1,arr2)
    end
  end
end
```

**Results**

```
arr1, arr2 = test(1_000_000, 800_000, 0.8)
bench(arr1, arr2)
                 user     system      total        real
justin       6.650000   0.160000   6.810000 (  6.855140)
btea         5.290000   0.100000   5.390000 (  5.439332)
success      2.970000   0.020000   2.990000 (  2.999598)
cary         3.970000   0.110000   4.080000 (  4.090756)

arr1, arr2 = test(2_000_000, 200_000, 0.5)
bench(arr1, arr2)
             user     system      total        real
justin      10.690000   0.190000  10.880000 ( 10.958374)
btea         8.650000   0.180000   8.830000 (  8.868550)
success      5.240000   0.010000   5.250000 (  5.268781)
cary         1.330000   0.020000   1.350000 (  1.351937)

arr1, arr2 = test(1_000_000, 1_000_000, 0.5)
bench(arr1, arr2)
                 user     system      total        real
justin      10.660000   0.160000  10.820000 ( 10.845127)
btea         5.810000   0.110000   5.920000 (  5.922358)
success      4.060000   0.020000   4.080000 (  4.078427)
cary         2.400000   0.040000   2.440000 (  2.447106)
```